# Let $P_n=a^{P_{n-1}}-1,\forall n=2,3,4...$ and let $P_1=a^x-1$ where $a\in R^+$ then evaluate $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{P_n}{x}$

Tags: limits

Let $P_n=a^{P_{n-1}}-1,\forall n=2,3,4...$ and let $P_1=a^x-1$ where $a\in R^+$ then evaluate $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{P_n}{x}$

In this question,i tried finding $P_n$ for limit,but it is very messy,raising to powers of one another,and appears not handleable.How can i find this limit.

Comment: $\ln(a)^n$. Prove it by induction, using L'Hospital.

Comment: For L Hospital,it has to keep coming in $\frac{0}{0}$ form.Isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, note that $P_n(0)=0$. Then, the desired limit is precisely $P_n'(0)$. We have
$$
P_n'(x)=P_{n-1}'(x)\,a^{P_{n-1}(x)}\,\ln a.
$$
Evaluate at $x=0$ to get
$$
P_n'(0)=P_{n-1}'(0)\,\ln a.
$$
Now it is easy tio get the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Look, what is $P_n$ at $x=0$? Apparently it is 0, so we can rewrite the limit in question as $\lim\limits_{x\to0}{P_n(x)-P_n(0)\over x-0}$, and that looks mighty like a derivative. Now, a derivative of $P_n$ is not that messy at all, given that we only need its value at 0.

Comment: Its answer is $(\ln a)^n$.We cannot arrive at this answer by differentiating just once.What should i do,@Ivan Neretin.